# Rewrite Drupal product title select list

Tags: php, drupal

I run a popular Drupal website that caters for the clubbing market. I retail events on my site using Drupal Commerce

To create an event(product) I have set up these fields :

- Event Title
- Event Date
- Event Price

When creating events, each event is a separate product with a different date.

Now on the node that lists that particular event, I title my products in a way so when select the event from the drop down select list it reads;

**Product Title(Event Name) -- Event date**

eg

- Boat Party - 12/07/15
- Boat Party - 13/07/15
- Boat Party - 14/07/15
- Boat Party - 15/07/15
- Boat Party - 16/07/15

What I need is rewrite function:

Instead of adding the date in the product title every time, is the correct function to rewrite the product title in the drop down as to include the date variable and price like as follows;

**Day,Month -- Product Title(event title) -- Price**

eg;

- 14th, May -- Boat Party -- £10
- 15th, May -- Boat Party -- £10
- 16th, May -- Boat Party -- £10
- 17th, May -- Boat Party -- £10
- 18th, May -- Boat Party -- £10

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel) module.
It can be used to automatically generate, for example, node title, or product title, using tokens. You will need [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) module as well.

You will need to use something like that as a pattern for product title *(pseudocode)*:

```
[product:event_date] -- [product:event_title] -- [product:price]
```